# Evaluation of $A$ in $2K(\sqrt{x}) = -\log(1 - x) + A + o(1)$ when $x \to 1^{-}$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, elliptic-integrals

Let $$K(k) = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1 - k^{2}\sin^{2} x}}$$ be the complete elliptic integral of first kind where $0 < k < 1$. Let $k' = \sqrt{1 - k^{2}}$ be the complementary modulus.

It is a standard result that as $x \to 1^{-}$ we have $$2K(\sqrt{x}) = -\log(1 - x) + A + o(1)$$ where $A$ is a positive constant and $o(1)$ denotes a term tending to zero as $x \to 1^{-}$.

I have also found two different approaches (from various online sources) to find value of constant $A$ and both give different values of $A$ so that one of the approaches is probably wrong. But I am not able to find fault in any of the approaches. Perhaps its a bit subtle mistake which I am overlooking. Please help me out in figuring this.

**Approach 1**: Clearly we have $$2K(\sqrt{x}) = 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1 - x\sin^{2}t}} = 2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{(1 - t^{2})(1 - xt^{2})}}$$ and $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{1 - xt}\,dt = -\log(1 - x)$$ so that we have $$2K(\sqrt{x}) + \log(1 - x) = \int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{(1 - t^{2})(1 - xt^{2})}} - \frac{x}{1 - xt}\right)\,dt$$ As $x \to 1^{-}$ the integral on right tends to $$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{2}{1 - t^{2}} - \frac{1}{1 - t}\right)\,dt = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{1 + t} = \log 2$$ so that the value of constant $A$ is $A = \log 2$.

**Approach 2**: Since $$2K(\sqrt{x}) = -\log(1 - x) + A + o(1)$$ as $x \to 1^{-}$, putting $x = 1 - k^{2}$ and letting $k \to 0^{+}$ we see that $$2K(k') = -2\log k + A + o(1)$$ or $$K(k') = -\log k + (A/2) + o(1)$$ as $k \to 0^{+}$.

Now $$\begin{aligned}K(k') &= \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1 - k'^{2}\sin^{2}x}}\\
&= \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{k'\sin x}{\sqrt{k^{2} + k'^{2}\cos^{2}x}}\,dx + \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1 - k'\sin x}{\sqrt{1 - k'^{2}\sin^{2}x}}\,dx\\
&= \int_{0}^{k'}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{k^{2} + t^{2}}} + \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\frac{1 - k'\sin x}{1 + k'\sin x}}\,dx\\
&= \log((1 + k')/k) + I\end{aligned}$$
Clearly $I$ tends to $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\frac{1 - \sin x}{1 + \sin x}}\,dx = \log 2$$ as $k \to 0^{+}$. Thus we get $K(k') = \log(2(1 + k')/k) + o(1)$ as $k \to 0^{+}$. Now we can see that $$\log\left(\frac{2(1 + k')}{k}\right) = \log\left(\frac{4}{k}\right) + \log\left(\frac{1 + k'}{2}\right) = \log(4/k) + o(1)$$ as $k \to 0^{+}$. It follows that $K(k') = -\log k + \log 4 + o(1)$ as $k \to 0^{+}$. Therefore we get $A/2 = \log 4$ or $A = \log 16$.

**Update**: After numerical feedback from @gammatester and also the wolfram reference my belief in the validity of second approach has increased significantly. With this value of $A = \log 16$ it is possible to prove that $$\lim_{k \to 0^{+}}\frac{1}{k^{2}}\cdot\exp\left(-\pi\frac{K(k')}{K(k)}\right) = e^{-A} = \frac{1}{16}$$ which can be independently verified by using theta functions with $k = \vartheta_{2}^{2}(q)/\vartheta_{3}^{2}(q)$ and $q = \exp\{-\pi K(k')/K(k)\}$.

To me it seems that in Approach 1, the passage to limit $x \to 1^{-}$ under the integral $$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{(1 - t^{2})(1 - xt^{2})}} - \frac{x}{1 - xt}\right)\,dt$$ is not allowed. But then there should be a way out to show that this integral tends to $\log 16$ (and not $\log 2$) as $x \to 1^{-}$.

Comment: Why do you think that both values for A are wrong? IMO the value $A=\ln16$ is correct, it is implicitly listed e.g. at http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticK/06/01/04/01/ and with my own multi-precision library I find the numerical values 
$$
A(1-10^{-10}) = 2.7725887228347422290064322435420843013716747\dots\\
A(1-10^{-20}) = 2.7725887222397812377859892122880080095977262\dots\\
A(1-10^{-30}) = 2.7725887222397812376689284858501688076800158\dots
$$
approaching  $\ln 16 =2.7725887222397812376689284858327062723020005\dots$

Comment: @gammatester: Actually i wanted to say that there is something wrong in one of the methods, but perhaps my language is suggesting otherwise. I will edit. In my view also $\log 16$ seems to be the correct value because there are many other facts in elliptic integral theory which support this. But I am not able to find the flaw in Approach 1.

Comment: A few more numerical experiments with
$$F(x)= \int_0^1\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{(1-t^{2})(1-xt^{2})}}-\frac{x}{1-xt}\right)\,dt$$ 
give the following results with Pari/GP's intnum (first set) and Maple's int (2nd set):
$$
F(1-10^{-10}) = 2.77258872283474222900643\\
F(1-10^{-20}) = 2.77258872223978123778601\\
F(1) = 0.6931471805599453034\\
$$
$$
F(1-10^{-10}) = 2.77258872283474222900643\\
F(1-10^{-20}) = 2.77258872223978123778598\\
F(1) = \ln(2)
$$
and therefore evidence for $F(1^{-}) = \ln 16.$ Interestingly Maple gives
`limit(F(x),x=1, left) = 4 ln(2)`, but I don't know how this is computed.

Comment: @gammatester: Thanks a lot for these numerical data. From what you mention it follows that $F(x)$ is discontinuous at $x = 1$. I think that the approach 1 (although it is from a reputed source) is wrong. The integral probably does not converge uniformly near $x = 1$ and hence taking limit under integral sign is not justified. I will try to contact the author of approach 1 and request him to kindly check and fix the calculation of the limit of the integral $F(x)$.

Comment: @gammatester: I would request you to add your comments as an answer. At least that way I can upvote your very helpful answer.