# On the asymptotic behavior of Elliptic integral near $k=1$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, elliptic-integrals

I was trying to prove that as $k\to1^-$,

$$
\int_0^1{\mathrm dx\over\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-k^2x^2}}\sim\frac12\log{1\over1-k}
$$

Since the original integral is difficult to work with, I split it:

$$
\int_0^1{\mathrm dx\over\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-k^2x^2}}=\int_0^k+\int_k^1
$$

in which it is evident that

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^k{\mathrm dx\over\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-k^2x^2}}
&=\int_0^k{\mathrm dx\over1-x^2}\cdot{\sqrt{1-x^2}\over\sqrt{1-k^2x^2}} \\
&=\frac12\int_0^k{\mathrm dx\over1-x}\cdot{\sqrt{1-x^2}\over\sqrt{1-k^2x^2}}+\mathcal O(1) \\
&=\frac12\int_0^k{\mathrm dx\over1-x}+\mathcal O\left(\int_0^k{1-k\over1-x}\mathrm dx\right)+\mathcal O(1) \\
&=\frac12\log{1\over1-k}+\mathcal O(1)
\end{aligned}
$$

I wonder how to show that $\int_k^1$ converges to zero as $k\to1^-$ so that I can complete the proof.

P.S. Alternative methods are welcome since I have been stuck on this for so much time :D

Comment: You can expand $dx/(1-x^2)$ in simple elements to get the following asymptotic: $-\log(1-k)/2+O(1)$ for the integral from zero to $k$. What remains is, of course, the integral from $k$ to $1$ of $((1-x^2)(1-k^2x^2))^{-1/2} \leq \frac{C}{\sqrt{1-k}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$. But the integral from $k$ to $1$ of $(1-x)^{-1/2}dx$ is $2\sqrt{1-k}$.

Comment: @Mindlack I just updated my question. Could you help me check the validity?

Comment: The standard result is $K(k) =\log\frac{4}{k'}+o(1)$ as $k\to 1^-$.

Comment: Also see related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/669327/72031

Comment: @TravorLZH You missed a minus sign in front of the $\log$ in your final result for the integral up to $k$.

Comment: @Gary Corrected, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @TravorLZH: I think this works. The end of my first comment sketches, I think, a way to bound the integral from $k$ to $1$.

Comment: Your result is not in agreement with K. Oldham, J. Myland, & J. Spanier, *An Atlas of Functions*, Springer. They give $K(k\to 1)=\ln(4/k'),\ k'=\sqrt{1-k^2}$.

Comment: @CyeWaldman Indeed they are not equal to each other, but they are asymptotically equivalent: $\log(4/k')\sim\log(1/\sqrt{(1+k)(1-k)})\sim\log(1/\sqrt{1-k})=\frac12\log(1/1-k)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $0<k<x<1$, then
\begin{align*}
\sqrt {1 - x^2 } \sqrt {1 - k^2 x^2 }  = \sqrt {1 - x} \sqrt {1 + x} \sqrt {1 - kx} \sqrt {1 + kx}   \ge \sqrt {1 - x} \sqrt {1 - k} .
\end{align*}
Hence,
$$
0 \leq \int_k^1 {\frac{{dx}}{{\sqrt {1 - x^2 } \sqrt {1 - k^2 x^2 } }}}  \le \frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 - k} }}\int_k^1 {\frac{{dx}}{{\sqrt {1 - x} }}}  = 2.
$$
This bound together with your estimate for the integral between $0$ and $k$ imply the desired asymptotics.