# Limit of $\int_0^1\left(\frac {2}{\sqrt {(1-t^2)(1-xt^2)}}-\frac{x}{1-xt}\right)\,dt$ as $x\to 1^{-}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

While going through [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4064023/72031) I was reminded of [one of my earlier questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/669327/72031) and I found that there is some unfinished business which needs some further exploration.

Let $$F(x) =\int_0^1\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{(1-t^2)(1-xt^2)}} -\frac{x}{1-xt}\right)\, dt=\int_0^1 f(x, t) \, dt\tag{1}$$ for $x\in[0,1]$.

Let's observe that $$\lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x,t)=\frac{1}{1+t}\tag{2}$$ and hence it is natural to expect that $\lim_{x\to 1^-}F(x)$ should equal $\int_0^1 dt/(1+t)=\log 2$ but numerical evidence as well as some amount of elliptic function theory tells (see one of my questions linked earlier for details) us that this particular limit is $4\log 2$.

This suggests that there is some weird behavior of integrand as $x\to 1^{-}$ (in particular the convergence is not uniform).

I would like to have this limit evaluated using some analysis related to convergence of integrand as $x\to 1^-$. Any help in this direction would be appreciated.

---

**Note**: I have asked a new question instead of bumping an old one. The old question is more about solution verification and is related to elliptic integrals. I wanted to have a different perspective which involves general issues of uniform convergence to handle the limit of this integral.

Comment: There is an interesting thing I found. Taylor series is not possible directly because in the expression to expand $$\frac{2}{1-t^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(1-x)\frac{t^2}{1-t^2}}}$$ $(1-x)\frac{t^2}{1-t^2}$ is not uniformly "small" enough on the interval $t\in[0,1]$ to justify a series truncation.

Comment: if you can bound the inside of the integral then you can apply Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem. I havent tried the details but it probably works

Comment: @metamorphy: well you can replace it with something else, but then there is additional burden of proving that the replacement does not change the limit (or if it changes, let its effect be also calculated).

Comment: You can re-express the limit as $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 1 - } \left[ {\pi {}_2F_1 \left( {\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1;x} \right) - \log (1 - x)} \right]
$$ and may use http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8.E10 to conclude.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The non-uniform convergence prevents the *direct* use of the *given* integrand.

However, the original problem is to compute $L=\lim\limits_{x\to1^-}\big(2K(\sqrt x)+\log(1-x)\big)$.

One may replace $x/(1-xt)$ with "something better" that approximates the original "elliptic" integrand uniformly (on $t\in(0,1)$ as $x\to1^-$) and is still *elementarily* integrable.

Let's replace $x$ by $x^2$ (to get rid of $\sqrt x$ everywhere), and consider $$F(x,t)=\frac1{\sqrt{(1-t^2)(1-x^2 t^2)}},\\G(x,t)=\frac1{a_x(1+t)\sqrt{(1-t)(1-xt)}},$$ where $a_x=\sqrt{(1+x)/2}$ is chosen to have $\lim\limits_{x\to1^-}\big(F(x,t)-G(x,t)\big)=0$ uniformly.

Now $\int_0^1 F(x,t)\,dt=K(x)$ and $\int_0^1 G(x,t)\,dt=a_x^{-2}\tanh^{-1}a_x$. Hence
\begin{align*}
L&=\lim_{x\to1^-}\big(2K(x)+\log(1-x^2)\big)
\\&=\lim_{x\to1^-}\big(\frac{1}{a_x^2}\log\frac{1+a_x}{1-a_x}+\log(1-x^2)\big)
\\&=\lim_{x\to1^-}\left[\log\left(\frac{1+a_x}{1-a_x}(1-x^2)\right)+\frac{1-x}{1+x}\log\frac{1+a_x}{1-a_x}\right]
\\&=\lim_{x\to1^-}\log\left(\frac{(1+a_x)^2}{1-a_x^2}(1-x^2)\right)
\\&=\lim_{x\to1^-}\log\big(2(1+x)(1+a_x)^2\big)=4\log 2.
\end{align*}

Comment: +1 there, but will decide acceptance/bounty award later. In the meanwhile I will check if I need some more details here.

Answer (score 6):

Remark: @metamorphy gave a nice solution. I constructed something slightly different
from @metamorphy's $G(x, t)$ due to the term $\sigma_x$.
I hope my answer is helpful as a supplement.

Let (replace $x$ with $x^4$ for convenience)
\begin{align*}
&G(x)\\
=\ & \int_0^1 \left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{(1 - t^2)(1 - x^4 t^2)}}  - \frac{x^4}{1 - x^4t}\right) \mathrm{d} t\\
=\ & \int_0^1 \left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{(1 + t)(1 + x^2t)}\sqrt{(1 - t)(1 - x^2 t)}}  - \frac{x^4}{1 - x^4t}\right) \mathrm{d} t\\
=\ & \int_0^1 \left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{(1 + t)(1 + t)}\sqrt{(1 - t)(1 - x^2 t)}}  - \frac{x^4}{1 - x^4t}\right) \mathrm{d} t\\
&\quad + \int_0^1 g(x, t)\mathrm{d} t \tag{1}
\end{align*}
where
$$g(x, t) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{1 + t}\sqrt{(1 - t)(1 - x^2 t)}}
\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x^2t}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + t}}\right).$$

First, we deal with the second integral in (1), i.e., $\int_0^1 g(x, t)\mathrm{d} t$.
Clearly, $g(x, t) \ge 0$ for all $x$ in $(0, 1)$ and all $t$ in $[0, 1)$. Also, we have,
for all $x$ in $(0, 1)$ and all $t$ in $[0, 1)$,
\begin{align*}
&g(x, t) \\
\le\ & \frac{2}{\sqrt{(1 - t)(1 - x^2)}}
\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x^2t}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + t}}\right)\\
=\ & \frac{2}{\sqrt{(1 - t)(1 - x^2)}}\frac{(1 - x^2)t}{(1 + x^2t)(1 + t)}\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x^2t}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + t}}\Big)^{-1}\\
\le \ & \frac{2}{\sqrt{(1 - t)(1 - x^2)}}(1-x^2)\\
=\ &  \frac{2\sqrt{1 - x^2}}{\sqrt{1 - t}}.
\end{align*}
Since $\int_0^1 \frac{2\sqrt{1 - x^2}}{\sqrt{1 - t}} \mathrm{d} t = 4\sqrt{1 - x^2}$,
we have $\lim_{x\to 1^{-}} \int_0^1 g(x, t)\mathrm{d} t = 0$.

Second, we deal with the first integral in (1), denoted by $H(x)$.
With the substitution $\frac{1 - x^2 t}{1 - t} = u^2$ (correspondingly $t = \frac{u^2 - 1}{u^2 - x^2}$),
we have (after doing the partial fraction decomposition for the integrand)
\begin{align*}
&H(x)\\
=\ & \int_1^\infty \left(\frac{\frac{2}{\sqrt{2 + 2x^2}}}{u - \sqrt{\frac{1 + x^2}{2}}}
- \frac{\frac{2}{\sqrt{2 + 2x^2}}}{u + \sqrt{\frac{1 + x^2}{2}}}
 + \frac{2(1 + x^2)u}{(1 + x^2)u^2 - x^2} - \frac{2u}{u^2 - x^2}\right)  \mathrm{d} u\\
=\ &\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{2 + 2x^2}}
\ln \frac{u - \sqrt{\frac{1 + x^2}{2}}}{u + \sqrt{\frac{1 + x^2}{2}}}
 + \ln\frac{(1 + x^2)u^2 - x^2}{u^2 - x^2}\right)\Big\vert_1^\infty\\
=\ & \ln(1 + x^2) - \frac{2}{\sqrt{2 + 2x^2}}
\ln \frac{1 - \sqrt{\frac{1 + x^2}{2}}}{1 + \sqrt{\frac{1 + x^2}{2}}} - \ln\frac{1}{1 - x^2}\\
=\ & \ln(1 + x^2) + \frac{2}{\sqrt{2 + 2x^2}}\ln 2 + \frac{4}{\sqrt{2 + 2x^2}}
\ln \left(1 + \sqrt{\frac{1 + x^2}{2}}\right)\\
&\quad + \left(1 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{2 + 2x^2}}\right)\ln(1 - x^2).
\end{align*}
It is easy to obtain $\lim_{x\to 1^{-}} H(x) = 4\ln 2$.

Thus, we have $\lim_{x\to 1^{-}} G(x) = 4\ln 2$.

We are done.

Comment: Very nice. +1 And this in more in line with my expectations.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks. It is basically the same as metamorphy's.

Comment: BTW, you have $x^2$ everywhere after $x\mapsto x^4$, so you would be fine with $x\mapsto x^2$ like me (intended to elaborate on my $\int_0^1 G(x,t)\,dt$ initially, but changed my mind later).

Comment: @metamorphy Thanks. You are right. At the beginning, the integrand has terms $\frac{1}{u - x}$ but they can be combined as $\frac{2u}{u^2 - x^2}$.